# how to reverse page after deleting any data in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i wanted to redirect my page to index after deleting row so i use `

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

`to reverse . i wanted this`http://127.0.0.1:8000/index`but it is showing`http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/index`
what is the proble please help me.

this is my view.py
`

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, "card/index.html")

def delete(request, id):
    dishes = dish.objects.get(id=id)
    dishes.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

`this is urls.py`

```
    path('index', views.index, name="index"),
    path('check', views.check, name="check"),
    path('delete/<int:id>', views.delete, name='delete'),
```

`

Comment: What is this Delete URL doing , where have you placed the form or link to this URL ? Post some information from where you are calling that delete. Looks like you have that form on Index so base url is already Index URL.
More context is required to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def index(request):
    return render(request, "card/index.html")

def delete(request, id):
    dishes = dish.objects.get(id=id)
    dishes.delete()
    return redirect("/index/")
```

Comment: it not works, what else i can do

Comment: Answer is update please check now

Answer (score 0):

Try using the conventional method of `reverse('app_name:url_name')`.

2nd method: Try passing the path directly in `reverse` like `reverse('/index')`

Comment: not working, what else i can do

Comment: Try adding end slash in your urls. Eg: `path('index/',views.index,name='index')`